# Proving that multiplication is a continuous map

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, continuity

I am trying to prove that multiplication $(x, y) \mapsto x y$ is a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is the following correct?

Consider arbitrary $a:=(a_1,a_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Consider arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. Set $\delta:=\frac{\epsilon}{2d}$, where $d$ satisfies the following condition:

$$ d \geq \max\{|\frac{\epsilon}{2d}+a_2|,|a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|, |a_1| \}\\ $$

First, we prove that such a $d\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ exists.

Suppose that $a_2 < 0$. Then $|a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|>|\frac{\epsilon}{2d}+a_2|$, for all $d>0$.

If $|a_1|\leq |a_2|$, then $\max\{|a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|, |a_1| \}=|a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|$ for all $d>0$ (since $|a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|$ is monotone decreasing for all $d>0$ and bounded below by $|a_2|$). Since, clearly, $d$ increases without bound, in $d$, there exists a $d>0$ such that $d \geq |a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|$. So there exists $d$ such that $d \geq \max\{|\frac{\epsilon}{2d}+a_2|,|a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|, |a_1| \}$.

If $|a_1| > |a_2|$, then $\max\{|a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|, |a_1| \}=|a_1|$ for all $d$ greater than some sufficiently large $d^{*}$. Clearly, there exists $d$ such that $d\geq \max\{d^{*}, |a_1|\}$. So there exists $d$ such that $d \geq \max\{|\frac{\epsilon}{2d}+a_2|,|a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|, |a_1| \}$.

Suppose $a_2 =0$. If $|a_2| \leq 0$, then $\max\{|\frac{\epsilon}{2d}+a_2|,|a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|, |a_1| \}=|\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|$ for all $d>0$. So there exists $d>0$ such that $d \geq \max\{|\frac{\epsilon}{2d}+a_2|,|a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|, |a_1| \}$. If $|a_2| > 0$, then $\max\{|\frac{\epsilon}{2d}+a_2|,|a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|, |a_1| \} = |a_1|$ for all $d$ greater than some sufficiently large $d^{*}$. Clearly, there exists $d$ such that $d \geq \max \{d^{*}, |a_1|\}$. So there exists $d$ such that $d \geq \max\{|\frac{\epsilon}{2d}+a_2|,|a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|, |a_1| \}$.

(The case in which $a_2>0$ is dealt with in a way analogous to that in which $a_2<0$).

Thus, pick a $d>0$ such that $d \geq \max\{|\frac{\epsilon}{2d}+a_2|,|a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|, |a_1| \}$. Set $\delta:= \frac{\epsilon}{2d}$.

We now prove the continuity of the multiplication map. Consider arbitary $x\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Set $\delta:= \frac{\epsilon}{2d}$. $\sqrt{(x_1-a_1)^2+(x_2-a_2)^2}< \delta  \implies  |x_1x_2-a_1a_2|=|a_1a_2-a_1x_2+a_1x_2-x_1x_2|=|a_1(a_2-x_2)+x_2(a_1-x_1)| \leq |a_1||(a_2-x_2)|+|x_2||(a_1-x_1)|<|a_1|\frac{\epsilon}{2d}+\max\{|\frac{\epsilon}{2d}+a_2|,|a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|\}\frac{\epsilon}{2d} \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$.

Note: $|x_2|< \max\{|\frac{\epsilon}{2d}+a_2|,|a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|\}$ follows from the fact that $\sqrt{(x_1-a_1)^2+(x_2-a_2)^2}< \delta \implies |x_2-a_2|<\frac{\epsilon}{2d} \implies a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}<x_2<\frac{\epsilon}{2d}+a_2 \implies |x_2|<\max\{|\frac{\epsilon}{2d}+a_2|,|a_2-\frac{\epsilon}{2d}|\}$.

Comment: Are you allowed to use sequences?

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$. If we suppose that $\|(x,y) - (a,b)\|_{2}\leq \delta_{\varepsilon}$, we may claim as well that
\begin{align*}
|xy - ab| & = |xy - xb + xb - ab|\\\\
& = |x(y - b) + b(x - a)|\\\\
& \leq |x||y - b| + |b||x - a|\\\\
& \leq (|a| + \delta_{\varepsilon})\delta_{\varepsilon} + |b|\delta_{\varepsilon}\\\\
& = \delta^{2}_{\varepsilon} + (|a| + |b|)\delta_{\varepsilon} := \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. Although, in the spirit of proof-verification, I would like to know whether my own attempt works. Thank you.